# mount remote file system using sshfs and without root permission

Tags: sshfs

I am using a admin'ed machine as a regular user and would like to mount some remote filesystem through sshfs. The machine doesn't have sshfs install. Is there a way that I can install it as a regular user and mount the remote filesystem?

Answer (score 14):

If you have access to the folder on the remote machine this should be possible in the following way:

```
sshfs user@remote.com:/foldertomount/ ~/mountpoint
```

The ssh user has to have permissions to the "foldertomount" while your local user has to have permission to the "mountpoint".

Comment: Ah~, my fault. The machine actually doesn't have sshfs install. My question should be whether it is possible to install it without root permission

Comment: You could possibly install it to your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can run sshfs from anywhere. As long as you have appropriate fuse permissions and ssh access it should work. You do have to mount within your home directory or somewhere else you normally have access to, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install sshfs, you can just use a binary version.

For this, download the `.deb` package e.g. from  [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/amd64/sshfs/2.4-1ubuntu1).

Then execute

```
ar x <PathToDebFile>
```

to unpack the .deb file and copy the sshfs-executeble from inside the resulting `data.tar.gz` archive to the computer.